# Multi-Modules maven pom

Tags: java, dependencies, maven-3

While writing for the first time a multi-modules maven pom, I wonder something.

First, here my parent pom :

```
    ...
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>project.room_management</groupId>
    <artifactId>room_management</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>room_management</name>
    <modules>
        <module>room_management_dao</module>
        <module>room_management_domain</module>
        <module>room_management_service</module>
        <module>room_management_gui</module>
    </modules>
    ...
```

and one of its children :

```
     ...
    <parent>
        <groupId>project.room_management</groupId>
        <artifactId>room_management</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>project.room_management</groupId>
    <artifactId>room_management_domain</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
   ...
```

Considering I don't need common modules to be share from parent to children poms, can I remove without "risks" the parent declaration into the children poms ? Or Maven does need it for modules compilation ?

Comment: What's wrong with having the `<parent>` declaration in the child poms? i.e. why do you want to remove it?

Comment: In fact, I would like to know weither this element take an important part for decisions concerning compilation of modules. Indeed, at this url : http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Multi-modules+projects, it is indicated that parent element is required in order to manage dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the `<parent>` section in the modules.

This primarily mean that each module must be independent - you cannot share configuration sections through the parent.

Comment: Note that given a project with modules, Maven should compile them in the right order to satisfy dependencies.  This is consistent with my experiences with "mvn clean install".

Answer (score 1):

In this example you need the parent element, cause you have dependencies between gui and your service (service to dao as well). Furthermore you need to define the dependencies between the modules to see which module uses which. On the other hand maven needs this information to predict the order of build of the modules which is important.
The next advantage of having such relationship is you can define the plugins/versions of dependencies in the parent module and many other things.

Comment: I try to compile the whole without parent elements and all happened well. Could you explain why you say that :  "Furthermore you need to define the dependencies between the modules to see which module uses which." Is it for simple knowledge for the reader or for a true internal maven mechanism ?

Comment: This project looks like a typical multi-module build which uses parent/child relationships and relationships between the modules. If you can work without it than ok just fine. But i assume you have relationships between the modules.

Comment: I've just realized that I misread your first comment ... Of course dependencies BETWEEN modules, maven needs it to consolidate decisions about compilation. I've just skipped knowledge of parent for children modules and all is fine. Thanks :)